# Is there an alternate timeline where Uncle Ben survives and Aunt May doesn't die?

Tags: spider-man, marvel

Uncle Ben is one of the few characters who has never officially been brought back from the dead *(I think)*. Which gave rise to the [phrase](http://oneofus.net/2014/11/no-one-stays-dead-except-uncle-ben/):

> No one in comics stays dead except Uncle Ben

There is a timeline, according to [Uncle Ben's wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Ben), where Ben survives but May dies:

> A storyline in Friendly Neighborhood Spider-Man has suggested that Ben may be alive. This Ben, however, was actually from an alternate timeline where Aunt May died in a random accident, leaving him to raise Peter. This alternate Ben came to the 616 reality as part of a plan devised by the Hobgoblin of 2211 to defeat the Spider-Men of different eras

Is there any *alternate timeline / dimension / universe* in which Ben never dies and Peter grows up with both Uncle Ben and Aunt May?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may be interested: Spider-verse includes a timeline where Ben became Spider-man, but May and Peter died.

Comment: @GeorgeT ha! That's crazy! Cheers!

Comment: I seem to recall there being one Earth-616 story (maybe it was an Ultimate) where Ben is returned to life briefly by Dr Strange, but everything is undone by the end of the book.

Comment: @phantom42 yeah I reckon there's a few of those _Bens alive until the end of this issue_ issues. There must be an established trope that covers this exact thing.

Comment: I prefer the older statement, "No one in comics stays dead except Bucky, Jason Todd, and Uncle Ben." The fact that the first two *didn't* stay dead just reinforces the point.

Comment: “part of a plan devised by the Hobgoblin of 2211” — not the the Hobgoblin of 2211! He’s the worst one!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. In the Spider Man crossover comic "[Spider-Verse Team-Up #1](http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Verse_Team-Up_Vol_1_1)", Spiderman Noir enters an alternate reality where both Uncle Ben and Aunt May are both alive and well.

[image]