# Has Uncle Ben ever received super powers?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, powers

> A common expression regarding comic book death was once “The only people who stay dead in comics are Bucky, Jason Todd, and Uncle Ben”.  <sub>- [Wikipedia: Comic book death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death)</sub>

Uncle Ben's death is one of the few consistencies in the Marvel Universe ([although even this isn't always the case](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80896/is-there-an-alternate-timeline-where-uncle-ben-survives-and-aunt-may-doesnt-die)). But Marvel loves finding powers for people who have never shown powers before, including a cosmic-powered Aunt May

[image]

But what about Uncle Ben? Has there ever been an instance where Uncle Ben has gotten super powers (either before or after his untimely death)?

Comment: "Not an imaginary story!"  Wait... So this actually happened?  That's kind of weird.

Comment: If wad isn't being sarcastic, it means it's supposed to be in canon.

Comment: She made a pie for Galactus.  Turns out it's much more filling than eating raw planets all the time.

Comment: Jason Todd [doesn't belong in that list anymore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Under_the_Hood).

Comment: @WadCheber If I'm not mistaken, they were telling the truth. It was not a hoax, a what if, or an imaginary story.  It was a dream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, in the Earth-3145 universe.**

Quoting from the [Marvel Comics Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/Benjamin_Parker_(Earth-3145)):

> Ben Parker received spider-powers when he accompanied his nephew Peter to a science demonstration where he was bitten by a spider. He decided to use his powers to help others despite Peter suggesting he go into show business, but retired out of grief after his foe the Emerald Elf discovered his identity and killed his wife and Peter.

His powers are “seemingly those of Peter Parker of Earth-616”, that is to say, Spider-man of the main Marvel Comics universe.