# Has J. Jonah Jameson ever received powers?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

Practically every unpowered named individual in the Marvel Multiverse has received powers in some What-If-iverse at some point. [I recently found out that Uncle Ben even became Spider-Man at one point.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92430/has-uncle-ben-ever-received-super-powers)

What about J.J. Jameson? Has he ever received any powers? Were they in the 616 or Ultimates universe? If so how did he cope?

Comment: I feel a strange compulsion to claim his incredibly charismatic editing style *is* his superpower.

Comment: After 70+ years of Spider Man, the answer to *every* single "**Has X happened in Spider Man?**" question is "*yes, repeatedly*"

Comment: @Richard yes, but "Is there a list of usually powerless individuals who have gotten powers?" would be too list-ish and probably off-topic.

Comment: There's also the "[*Captured by J. Jonah Jameson*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tz0Ng6zz490)" episode of the [*Spider-Man*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_%281967_TV_series%29) TV series by [*Ralph Bakshi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Bakshi). It's note really *Jameson* getting powers, but a Spider-man hunter robot, with Jameson's face, that Jameson sponsors to capture Spidey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During [Spider-Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Island), J. Jonah Jameson gained spider powers.

[image]

He manages to defeat a spider-slayer, so I guess he does ok. This was in 616.

Comment: ...are his trousers falling down in that picture?!?!

Comment: You don't want to see where his web comes from...

Comment: His mustache obviously.